# python pandas if for

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file with many columns in it. Let me give you people an example.

```
A B C D 
1 1 0  
1 1 1 
0 0 0
```

I want to do this.

```
if col-A first row value == 1 AND col-B first row value == 1 AND col-C first row value == 1;
        then put "FIC" in first row of Col-D
   else:
        enter "PI"
```

I am using pandas.

There are more than 1500 rows and I want to do this for every row. How can I do this? Please help

Comment: can you fix your input? you have 4 columns for only 3 values. Also please provide the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need test if all values are `1` per filtered columns use:

```
df['D'] = np.where(df[['A','B','C']].eq(1).all(axis=1), 'FIC','PI')
```

Or if only `0,1` values in filtered columns:

```
df['D'] = np.where(df[['A','B','C']].all(axis=1), 'FIC','PI')
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
   A  B    C   D
0  1  1  NaN NaN
1  1  1  1.0 NaN
2  0  0  0.0 NaN


m1 = df[['A','B','C']].all(axis=1)
m2 = df[['A','B','C']].isna().any(axis=1)
df['D'] = np.select([m2, m1], ['ZD', 'FIC'],'PI')
print (df)
   A  B    C    D
0  1  1  NaN   ZD
1  1  1  1.0  FIC
2  0  0  0.0   PI
```

Comment: thank you jezrael. It works. great. There are some rows with NaN values. I don't want these rows with either of the output i.e. FIC and PI. instead "ZD"

Comment: @MuhammadRehan - can you check `EDIT` ?

Comment: Its not working. It gives me FIC for Nan values too. Instead of ZD

Comment: @MuhammadRehan - You are right. I change solution for first test `m2` for misisng values and then `m1`. Answer was EDITed.

Comment: Thank You jezrael. Let me tell you people like you and @Corralien makes this world beautiful. So nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

Without `numpy` you can use:

```
df['D'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].astype(bool).all(1).replace({True: 'FIC', False: 'PI'})
print(df)

# Output
   A  B  C    D
0  1  1  0   PI
1  1  1  1  FIC
2  0  0  0   PI
```

Comment: thank you Corralien for your answer. Mr. jezrael answer works too. Yours too. Sorry I can accept only one.